# SharePoint Designer Workflow to Visio > Works but visio is missing

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, visio

SharePoint Designer Workflow Export to Visio works fine. However, in Visio import only imports the diagram (figures). Non of the logic (the actual conditions), verbiage are missing. Is it possible to import everything.

Answer (score 1):

Which Visio-Version do you have? We have only Professional that's why we can't export useful parts of a workflow. You need Visio Premium to perform.
Microsoft says that Visio does not support any steps, so I guess they also don't support conditions.
(it's a comment, but have to low reputation)

Comment: I am using visio premium.

Comment: My answer came from http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/sharepoint-workflow-validation-issues-in-visio-HA101893811.aspx?CTT=1  using the search from Microsoft on their site http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/results.aspx?&ex=2&qu=workflow%20designer%20visio. But I guess you already had a look at this side.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the stage to outline for getting action, conditions working

Regards,
Ravi Thapliyal

Comment: Provide more details (an example) on how to achieve that please.